# Filter results in loopback change-stream

Tags: strongloop, loopback, eventsource

does Strongloop Loopback support filtering in change-streams?

The following works for all model changes, but I am only interested in changes of parts of the model. Can I add filtering to the EventSource-URL?

```
var src = new EventSource('/api/mymodel/change-stream?_format=event-source');

var changes = createChangeStream(src);
changes.on('data', function(update) {
      console.log("data changed...", JSON.stringify(update));  
});
```

Thx

Comment: HI,
Did you get any solution for this?